# Golang cookie not deleting

Tags: go

In trying to test the following code:

```
//SetSingleSignOn Sets the cookie to allow for single sign cross applications.
func SetSingleSignOn(w http.ResponseWriter, token string) {
    http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
        Name:     ssoCookie,
        Value:    token,
        Path:     "/",
        HttpOnly: false,
        Secure:   false,
        Domain:   "localhost",
        Expires:  time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 7),
        MaxAge:   0,
    })
}

//DestroySingleSignOn Gets rid of single sign on, in case a user logs out of the application.
func DestroySingleSignOn(r *http.Request, w http.ResponseWriter) {
    cookie, err := r.Cookie(ssoCookie)
    if err != nil || cookie.Value == "" {
        return
    }

    cookie = &http.Cookie{
        Name:     ssoCookie,
        Path:     "/",
        HttpOnly: false,
        Secure:   false,
        Domain:   "localhost",
        Expires:  time.Now(),
        MaxAge:   -1}

    http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
}
```

I come across an apparent false fail.

All my tests against `SetSingleSignOn` pass, but the sanity test against `DestroySingleSignOn` fails.

**The test**

looks something like this:

```
t.Run("SignedOnFirst", func(t *testing.T) {

    req := httptest.NewRequest("POST",
        "localhost:42100",
        nil)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()

    SetSingleSignOn(w, "12446rewa12314")

    // assert.NotPanics(t, func() { DestroySingleSignOn(req, w) })
    DestroySingleSignOn(req, w)

    // get the cookie
    res := w.Result()
    fmt.Println(res.Cookies())

    assert.Equal(t, 1, len(res.Cookies()))
    cookie := *res.Cookies()[0]
    // cookie should be named ssoCookie
    assert.Equal(t,
        ssoCookie,
        cookie.Name)

    // cookie should have already expired
    assert.True(t,
        time.Now().After(cookie.Expires))

})
```

It's as if the `http.SetCookie(w, cookie)` was never invoked at all! Even more bizarre, is when I scrap the function call for straight up

```
http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
    Name:     ssoCookie,
    Path:     "/",
    HttpOnly: false,
    Secure:   false,
    Domain:   "localhost",
    Expires:  time.Now(),
    MaxAge:   -1}
```

it seems to work (the last cookie is inactive), but now there's **two** cookies in `res.Cookies()`!

What could be causing this?

Comment: Even setting `MaxAge` to `3600` in `SetSingleSignOn` doesn't change anything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `DestorySingleSignOn` function, you begin with this block:

```
cookie, err := r.Cookie(ssoCookie)
if err != nil || cookie.Value == "" {
    return
}
```

Notice, you are checking for the cookie on the *request*, but the cookie has only been set on the *response*. You would need to issue a request to get the initial cookie set, and then issue a second request with that cookie for this to work.

```
t.Run("SignedOnFirst", func(t *testing.T) {

    req := httptest.NewRequest("POST",
        "localhost:42100",
        nil)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()

    SetSingleSignOn(w, "12446rewa12314")

    // get the initial cookie
    res := w.Result()
    cookie := res.Cookies()[0]

    // issue a second request with the cookie
    req = httptest.NewRequest("POST",
        "localhost:42100",
        nil)
    req.AddCookie(cookie)
    w = httptest.NewRecorder()

    // assert.NotPanics(t, func() { DestroySingleSignOn(req, w) })
    DestroySingleSignOn(req, w)

    // get the new cookie
    res = w.Result()
    fmt.Println(res.Cookies())

    assert.Equal(t, 1, len(res.Cookies()))
    cookie = *res.Cookies()[0]
    // cookie should be named ssoCookie
    assert.Equal(t,
        ssoCookie,
        cookie.Name)

    // cookie should have already expired
    assert.True(t,
        time.Now().After(cookie.Expires))

})
```